# Polar coordinates and Jacobian

Tags: probability-distributions, polar-coordinates, density-function, jacobian, change-of-variable

Let $(V,W)$ a point in the circle of unity radius chosen in accordance with the following rules. First, let $R$ a random number uniform in $(0,1)$. Second, you choose a point $X$ on the circumference of radius $R$ just selected. Find the density of point $(V,W)$.

---

Well, by the inverse transformation I know that $V=Rcos\theta$, $W=Rsin\theta$, $R=\sqrt{V^2+W^2}$ and $\theta=arctan \frac{W}{V}$. So why professor writes $J=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{V}} & \frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{W}}\\ 
\frac{\partial{\theta}}{\partial{V}} & \frac{\partial{\theta}}{\partial{W}} 
\end{bmatrix}$ and not $J=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{R}} & \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{\theta}}\\ 
\frac{\partial{W}}{\partial{R}} & \frac{\partial{W}}{\partial{\theta}} 
\end{bmatrix}$? Could you please help me to understand?
In other terms, why we have the application $(R,\theta)\rightarrow(V,W)$ and not $(V,W)\rightarrow(R,\theta)$?

Comment: Without a bit more detail, it's difficult to help. The professor can start by writing either and end up with a correct solution; it depends what they write before and after and why they are writing whatever they are writing.

Also, do you mean that $X$ is chosen uniformly on $[0,2pi]$? to give an angle? So $X$ is $\theta$?

Comment: @T_M Thanks for your answer. Look, the solution is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfpCA.png) and the text of the exam is exactly how I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why one choice of $J$ seems more intuitive to you than the other choice but let me try to explain.

The process described says that the radius $R$ and the angle $X$ are chosen uniformly at random from the intervals $(0,1)$ and $[0,2\pi)$ respectively. So although it's a radius and an angle:

***the point $(R,X)$ is chosen uniformly from the rectangle $(0,1)\times [0,2\pi)$***.

This might be a bit counterintuitive but is completely correct from an analytic point of view. In particular we can see that the density of $(R,X)$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, which means that if $A \subset (0,1)\times [0,2\pi)$, then
\begin{equation}\tag{i}
\mathbb{P}\bigl( (R,X) \in A\bigr) = \int_A \frac{1}{2\pi}\, drd\theta.
\end{equation}

On the other hand, the point $(V,W)$ is the cartesian coordinates of a point in the disc. So:

***the point (V,W) is chosen randomly - according to some density that you are asked to find - from the unit disc.***

The density of $(V,W)$ is going to be a function $f(v,w)$ with the property that if $B$ is a subset of the unit disc $D$, then
\begin{equation}\tag{ii}
\mathbb{P}\bigl( (V,W) \in B\bigr) = \int_B f(v,w)\, dvdw.
\end{equation}

Let $F : D \to (0,1)\times [0,2\pi)$ be defined by
$$
F(x,y) = \Bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan \frac{y}{x} \Bigr) = (r,\theta).
$$
This is the function that maps the disc to the rectangle. You could start with the inverse of this function and still get the correct answer at the end; it doesn't matter as long as you understand the way the transformations work. Since $V = R\cos X$ and $W = R\sin X$, notice that
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigl( (V,W) \in B\bigr) = \mathbb{P}\bigl( F^{-1}(R,X) \in B\bigr) = \mathbb{P}\bigl( (R,X) \in F(B)\bigr).
$$
By (i) this is equal to
$$
\int_{F(B)} \frac{1}{2\pi} drd\theta.
$$
So now you want to transform this integral to put it in the form on the right-hand side of (i), i.e. transform it to $\int_B [ \dots ] dvdw$. Can you see now why the professor proceeded as they did?